# escaping column name as query parameter

Tags: python, parameters, escaping, sql-injection, pymssql

I was redoing a query to prevent SQL injection, but can't figure out how to escape the column name.

This code won't work (example 1):

```
cursor.execute(
"UPDATE ttt SET status = 'Good' FROM table ttt WHERE %s = %s';",
('param1', 'param2',))

sql_server_connection.commit()
```

This will work (example 2):

```
cursor.execute(
"UPDATE ttt SET status = 'Good' FROM table ttt WHERE param1 = %s';",
('param2',))
```

I need to pass 2 parameters to my query and do it safe way (to prevent SQL injection).

I can make it work, by passing simple string, but this is not the safe way.

How can one escape column name and value with single cursor.execute command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a parameterized query, parameters can only be used to supply column *values*, not column *names*. Therefore, you need to use string manipulation to insert the column name and then use a parameter to specify the value. For example, with Python3:

```python
column_name = 'param1'
column_value = 'param2'
cursor.execute(f"UPDATE ttt SET status = 'Good' WHERE [{column_name}] = %s", (column_value,))
```

In Python2

```python
column_name = 'param1'
column_value = 'param2'
sql = "UPDATE ttt SET status = 'Good' WHERE [{}] = %s".format(column_name)
cursor.execute(sql, (column_value,))
```

Comment: python 2.7 does not support a "F" prefix. Is there workaround?

Comment: Thanks. Can you also explain what is square brackets role here? [ {} ]

Comment: @NirVana - Square brackets are T-SQL's standard way of delimiting table/column names that might contain spaces or "funny characters". `... WHERE tax rate = ...` won't work, but `... WHERE [tax rate] = ...` will.

Comment: This does not answer the question how to escape the column names properly, just how to insert them.